# How to Create complex Array Structure in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have to make this kind of structure in array;

We have three ( 3 ) variables which creates this structure:

```
$numberOfParticipants = 38; // 38 is example
$numberOfParticipantsPerHeat = 8 // 8 is example
$numberOfHeats = 5; // 5 is example
```

Based on this variables I have this table:

[image: The table that I have]

The problem is that, I can't place the ' - ' or null after 31 OR 38. The task is that i have to make the arrays of array "almost equal" like the photo and must depend on the variables above. By the way, after I create the correct list I will slice the array to 5 or 6 or whatever parts I need this is not the problem, the problem is that I have to parse the list like this first. This is what I tried so far:

```
    $calc1 = (int)round($numberOfParticipants * $numberOfParticipantsPerHeat, -1); //First round the numberOfParticipants to closest integer by 10


    $readyArr = [];


    for ($i = 1; $i <= $calc1; $i++) {

        if ($i <= $numberOfParticipants) {

            $readyArr[$i] = $i;

        } else {

            $readyArr[$i] = null;
        }

    }
```

The problem with this snippet is that it places the null at the end of the list not after 31, or based on the var.
This is the result I have:

```
array:40 [▼
  1 => 1
  2 => 2
  3 => 3
  4 => 4
  5 => 5
  6 => 6
  7 => 7
  8 => 8
  9 => 9
  10 => 10
  11 => 11
  12 => 12
  13 => 13
  14 => 14
  15 => 15
  16 => 16
  17 => 17
  18 => 18
  19 => 19
  20 => 20
  21 => 21
  22 => 22
  23 => 23
  24 => 24
  25 => 25
  26 => 26
  27 => 27
  28 => 28
  29 => 29
  30 => 30
  31 => 31
  32 => 32
  33 => 33
  34 => 34
  35 => 35
  36 => 36
  37 => 37
  38 => 38
  39 => null
  40 => null
]
```

The Array after partition  I want should be:

```
 array(
            0 => array(0 => 1,  1 => 2,  2 => 3,  3 => 4,  4 => 5,  5 => 6,  6 => 7,  7 => 8,),
            1 => array(0 => 9,  1 => 10, 2 => 11, 3 => 12, 4 => 13, 5 => 14, 6 => 15, 7 => 16,),
            2 => array(0 => 17, 1 => 18, 2 => 19, 3 => 20, 4 => 21, 5 => 22, 6 => 23, 7 => 24,),
            3 => array(0 => 25, 1 => 26, 2 => 27, 3 => 28, 4 => 29, 5 => 30, 6 => 31, 7 => null,),
            4 => array(0 => 32, 1 => 33, 2 => 34, 3 => 35, 4 => 36, 5 => 37, 6 => 38, 7 => null,),
        );
```

Every help, every clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So, do you want the result after partition or in raw array?

Comment: Basically doesn't actually matter for me because if i have the raw array i will partition it with another function which is working well if the raw array is formatted in the way i need, but you can offer combined solution f you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to know about the target structure:

How many players are in the first (which will always be the largest, if only by one) set.

```
$playersPerHeat = ceil($numberOfParticipants / $numberOfHeats);
// note this replaces your hard-coded $numberOfParticipantsPerHeat
```

You also need to know how many heats actually have that many, that is how many heats are actually full.

```
$fullHeats = $numberOfParticipants % $numberOfHeats ?: $numberOfHeats;
// The ?: bit means that if we get zero (ie. all equal heats), then we
// count all the heats instead, since they're all full.
```

Now it's easy!

```
$players = range(1,$numberOfParticipants);
$heats = array_merge(
    array_chunk(
        array_slice($players, 0, $fullHeats * $playersPerHeat),
        $playersPerHeat
    ),
    array_chunk(
        array_slice($players, $fullHeats * $playersPerHeat),
        $playersPerHeat - 1
    )
);
```

That's it! [Demo](https://ideone.com/PA3GRM)

Comment: Alright, thank you very much ! Now the point is that how to insert the dash or null straight to the $heats ? So i can output it in javascript for example